# Is it safe to give a sugar daddy my bank account and routing number?

Tags: sugar-daddy

So I have a potential sugar daddy and he is asking me for my bank account number and routing number so he can deposit money into my account every week is that safe or is this a scam. Emergency pls answer quickly and real answers only

Comment: No, it is not safe, and is certainly a scam. Search "Sugar Daddy" on this site and you will find plenty of examples of people asking the same question.

Comment: You can read about the sugar daddy tag at https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/sugar-daddy/info and also see the top voted questions at https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy for more information

Comment: It's obviously a scam.  BUT IT'S WORSE THAN THAT.  As soon as you *give him your information* you can be ARRESTED for money laundering.  It's exactly like being a "mule" for drug transporters.

Answer (score 14):

No.  Unless you are having sex with him* - the traditional meaning of the term "sugar daddy" - it's a scam.  Get real here: what's so wonderful about you that strangers are going to give you lots of money and expect nothing in return?

*And if you are, he can give you cash or a check.  Otherwise safe sex is a topic for another site.

Answer (score 7):

No it is absolutely a scam. Search this site for "[Sugar daddy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy)" and see how badly this can go.

There are numerous safer ways to transfer money like Venmo,cash or checks or just about anything where you don't have to give them access to your banking info. But don't bother, they aren't really wanting to pay you. They are trying to steal your money.

Comment: Anyone OP has written a check to has account/routing number, how is that especially dangerous? Most of the similar questions they are asking for account login.

Comment: Maybe this first question for only the account and routing umber is just a start, and the next question from the "sugar daddy" to its victim is like "oh, I forgot, I need your username and password as well".

Comment: Nah, the sugar daddies don't need the login info. They just transfer some money to the mark, get the mark to pay someone else (laundering the money) and then they or the bank reverse the transfer.

Comment: @glglgl it's a straightforward, well-known scam. (mkennedy explains it).  it's best to not add confusion / complications on "scam questions".  Every single person who answers or comments should simply type "yes it is a well-known scam" and close the question.